# How to add elements in array using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var total=0;
var Status = [];
for(i=0 ; i<target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[3].cells().length ; i++)
{
Status[i] = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Activity List Table"].cells()[i].staticTexts()[3].name();
total+=parseInt(Status[i]);
}
```

I am storing all the cell values in status[i] , now i want to take the sum of all the values in status[i]

Comment: you can `Array.push()`.

Comment: what is the issue? Is it not working?

Comment: total = Status[i].push(); , is this what you are suggesting ?

Comment: No its not working Mr Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go with this:

```
   var total=0;
    var Status = [];
    for(i=0 ; i<target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[3].cells().length ; i++)
    {
        Status.push(target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Activity List Table"].cells()[i].staticTexts()[3].name());
    total+=parseInt(Status[i]);
    }
```

It will push the new item in the array at the end of it.

Comment: there must be some error with the expression you are passing I guess.. My best guess without looking in the object you are trying to get data from is that, you either have an issue in the for loop itself, where you are not looking in the right place to begin with or not listing it properly (missing [i])

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push):

```
Status.push(target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Activity List Table"].cells()[i].staticTexts()[3].name());
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you sure the expression is working? Maybe you are pushing the wrong value to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var total=0;
    var Status = [];
    for(i=0 ; i<target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[3].cells().length ; i++)
    {
        var myVal = target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Activity List Table"].cells()[i].staticTexts()[3].name();
        Status.push(myVal);
    total+=parseInt(myVal);
    }
```

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/t72fxg6n/1/). If above is not working then must be problem with your Data. Try `console.log(target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[3].cells())`  and what you are getting.